# DNS: retry and TTL values

Tags: dns

I read some explanations on the Internet on the topic and also BIND and DNS 4th Edition chapters 4.2 (Setting Up Zone Data) and 8.4 (Changing TTLs).
Still I have some doubts.
A brief refresh first of all. ;-)

**Refresh time** is the interval time between two queries done by the slave to check if the serial number of a zone on the primary DNS (or upstream server, correct me if I'm wrong) has changed or not.

**TTL** is the time during which a slave DNS server caches an entry (A or AAAA normally) before refreshing its value retrieved from the master.

Let's use a practical example: the refresh value on the secondary is 7200 (3hours) and the TTL is 86400 (1day), regardless if they're in use or not in the real world. Let's say pippo.example.com resolves into 192.0.2.98.
Imagine the slave has just retrieved this entry and hence the entry's lifetime has few seconds.

Now pippo.example.com changes from 192.0.2.98 to 192.0.2.78 on the primary. On the primary we'll change the serial number too and when after three hours the slave queries the master it'll see a higher serial number and it'll retrieve the full zone and hence also the new IP address for pippo.example.com.

QUESTION 1:
From my understanding the TTL is not respected. Am I right?
I mean why the slave would keep the old cached entry if that entry's got a new value on the primary?

QUESTION 2: if what I wrote above is true, why everybody uses the tecnique of lowering the TTL before replacing an IP address of a FQDN?

I guess my first reasoning is not correct and it might be that I'm missing something obvious but that at the moment I can't answer by myself. Thanks in advance to anyone who clarifies and/or to points me to docs that explain that.

Comment: Slave or secondary has the zone, so it's authoritative.  All other names servers besides the primary and secondaries are caching only with respect to the zone in question.  The refresh affects zone transfers while the TTLs affect caching.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. This question seems to be more related to server/computer configuration which is off topic as defined by the community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, in the end the question boils down to the difference between secondary and cache DNS servers that was not clear to me in advance. IMO running a DNS server is not about the configuration of a server because its settings influence other servers too and as such I'd say that the DNS is a professional networking topic. IKE/ISAKMP looks much more clearly a networking topic but even for that one may ask for clarification between proxy-ID and split-tunnel that eventually turns to be a setting on the router/firewall (a server with StrongSwan Linux box, for instance)

Comment: Moreover I see that somebody else has added the tag "protocol-theory" that I guess is pertinent to this forum. So I would n't say that the thread is clearly off topic but again since I'm new I'll live with the decision you are going to take.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some zone, a DNS server can have different responsibilities:

- ***Master*** (aka ***primary***) server: authoritative server for the zone
- ***Slave*** (aka ***secondary***) server: authoritative server for the zone which gets its data from another authoritative source (a master) through a zone transfer
- ***Caching*** server (aka ***resolver***): any DNS server which receives a query about the zone and gets records from an authoritative source for this zone, chaching the records for a faster response on future queries.

You seem to be confusing slaves and caching servers. Note that, unlike the masters and slaves, the caching servers are not operated by or on behalf of the owner of the zone, but can be any DNS server in the world that has obtained information about the zone.

The *refresh time* tells a *slave* when to check for new information from the master server.

The *TTL* is meant for *caching servers*, telling them for how long information can be cached.

*QUESTION 1:* Yes, a slave server will update its zone information through a zone transfer after refresh_time seconds.

*QUESTION 2:* Lowering the TTL before a DNS change prevents DNS servers around the world from caching the old IP address after it has been changed. Slave servers can be explicitly notified of a change, but sending a low TTL with responses is the only way to incluence the behavior of caching servers.

Comment: You're completely true @Gerben. Many thanks